# How can I pass modal data? bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5.3, bootstrap-modal

My javascript code like this :

```
<script>
    for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        res += `<td class="image" id="thumbs-view-`+i+`" 
                    data-toggle="modal" 
                    data-target="#modal-option-`+i+`"
                    data-photo='${JSON.stringify(photo[i])}'
                    data-id="`+id+`"
                >
                    <img src="/img/thumbs/`+photo[i].name+`">
                </td>`;
    }
</script>
```

My modal like this :

```
@for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) 
<div id="modal-option-{{$i}}" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    ...
        <div class="modal-body">
            ...
            <a href="#" id="edit-{{$i}}"
               data-toggle="modal"
               data-target="#modal-edit-{{$i}}"
               data-photo="/* Value shown here */" 
               data-id="/* Value shown here */"
            >
                Edit
            </a>
            ...
        </div>
    ...
</div><!-- /.modal -->
@endfor
```

data-photo and data-id have value

If the td clicked, it will call modal

I want to display the value of data photo and data id from javascript to data photo and data id in the modal

So if the modal open, data photo and data id in the modal have value

How can I do it?

Comment: You can open your modal with javascript instead of what you are doing above.  That will let you set the content before it opens. https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp

Comment: @Bindrid, I do not see anything that helps there